# Как работает выдача сайта по ключевым словам?

Tags: веб-программирование, seo

Всем привет, сделал сайт, добавил в яндекс веб мастер, сайт видно в поиски только если ввести его название, но как сделать так что бы он выдавался по определённому запросу (например: смотреть такой-то сериал). Есть теги с ключевыми словами meta name="keywords"(но насколько знаю, они сейчас не особо учитываются), а тогда как вообще происходит связь ключевых слов с вашим сайтом, надо что бы на него чаще люди заходили, тогда и в выдаче он буде на высоте, или как это вообще устроено ?

Comment: Если грубо, то учитывается содержимое сайта и, что довольно важно, текст в ссылках с других сайтов на ваш сайт. Т.е. если другие сайты пишут в ссылках (или около них) "смотрите тут сериал такой-то", то это добавляет вашему ранг по этим ключевым словам.

Comment: Вроде "keywords" уже не влияет не на что для поисковиков, не?

Answer (score 4):

> Есть теги с ключевыми словами meta name="keywords"(но насколько знаю,
> они сейчас не особо учитываются)

**[Гугл игнорирует этот мета](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/special-tags)** и при определенных условиях может рассматривать значение  этого мета как сигнал спама, например **[Нерелевантные ключевые слова](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/irrelevant-keywords)**. Бинг вообще считает наличие этого мета как **[сигнал спама](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2014/10/03/blame-the-meta-keyword-tag)**.

> как вообще происходит связь ключевых слов с вашим сайтом, надо что бы
> на него чаще люди заходили, тогда и в выдаче он буде на высоте, или
> как это вообще устроено ?

Процесс узнавания Гугл содержания вашего вебсайта довольно подробно описано в их статье **[Как работает Google Поиск](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/beginner/how-search-works)**, например:

> **Сканирование**
>
> Обнаружив URL страницы, робот Googlebot посещает ее (сканирует) с
> целью получить сведения о том, что на ней опубликовано. При этом он
> анализирует как текстовый, так и нетекстовый контент, а также общий
> дизайн, чтобы определить, где именно страница должна появляться в
> результатах поиска. Чем точнее будут классифицированы материалы вашего
> сайта, тем точнее мы сможем сопоставлять их с поисковыми запросами
> пользователей.
>
> **Индексирование**
>
> После обнаружения страницы нужно выяснить, какого
> рода контент на ней размещен. Этот процесс называется индексированием.
> Google анализирует контент страницы, систематизирует найденные на ней
> изображения и видеофайлы и т. д. Полученная информация сохраняется в
> индексе Google – огромной базе данных, размещенной на множестве
> компьютеров.

> **Выдача результатов и ранжирование**

> Когда пользователь вводит запрос, Google на основе
> многочисленных факторов ищет в своем индексе самые подходящие
> результаты. Среди прочего учитывается местоположение, язык и тип
> устройства пользователя (обычный компьютер или телефон). Например,
> результаты по запросу "ремонт велосипедов" будут различаться в
> зависимости от того, находитесь вы в Париже или в Гонконге.

Для определения релевантности содержания какой-то страницы для каждого поискового запроса, Гугл использует **[Двунаправленные представления кодировщика от Transformers (BERT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BERT_(language_model))** - *это основанный на Transformer метод машинного обучения для предварительного обучения обработке естественного языка (NLP)*.

Для семантического поиска, Гугл имеет базу данных **[Knowledge Graph](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Graph)** (рус. Сеть знаний; дословно Граф знаний) — *семантическая технология и база знаний, используемая Google для повышения качества своей поисковой системы с семантическо-поисковой информацией, собранной из различных источников*.

Каждая страница веб-сайта является HTML документом, и, соответственно,содержание каждого документа имеет субъект содержания, которые, в свою очередь, имеют суб-субъекты. Дерево субъектов документа создает иерархическую структуру, с использованием **[HTML элементов заголовков](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)**. Такая структура помогает поисковику определить тему содержания страницы и темы вложенных секций/параграфов содержания. Содержание заголовков могут иметь ключевые слова, или **сущности содержания**. В свою очередь содержание секции/параграфа, которое представлено в заголовке, также может иметь ключевые слова и фразы уже с их более подробным описанием.

Если ваше содержание имеет **[поисковую оптимизацию](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/beginner/seo-starter-guide)** и имеет высокий уровень надежности и достоверности, то высока вероятность того факта, что страницы вашего вебсайта будут привлекать трафик целевых пользователей, которые ищут онлайн, сущности/ключевые слова, связанные с содержанием вашего веб-сайта.

Answer (score 2):

> но как сделать так что бы он выдавался по определённому запросу (например: смотреть такой-то сериал)

Стоит учитывать популярность запроса, так по запросу "смотреть мандалорец" будет предложено 1000 сайтов (цифры для примера), а вот "смотреть кобра кай" выведет только 10 сайтов, что позволит вашему сайту оказаться в выдаче на первой странице по малопопулярному запросу.

так же необходимо обращать внимание и на другие факторы ранжирования. Если запрос производится с мобильного телефона, а сайт не оптимизирован под маленькие экраны, то скорее всего в выдаче он окажется в самом низу. У каждого фактора разный приоритет:

- Поведенческие факторы
- Поисковые факторы
- Доменные факторы
- Технические факторы
- Контентные и текстовые факторы
- Региональные факторы
- Коммерческие факторы
- Внешние факторы
- и другие